# Dovecot can not detect user

Tags: postfix, dovecot

System specification: Ubuntu 18.04, Postfix 3.3.0, dovecot 2.2.33.2

---

I followed [this vimbadmin guide](https://github.com/opensolutions/ViMbAdmin/wiki/Mail-System-Install-on-Ubuntu). But not successful. Dovecot does not detect mailbox.

I ran this code:

```
postmap -q fandi@mysite.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
```

i got:

```
maildir:/srv/vmail/icodeformoney.com/fandi/mail:LAYOUT=fs
```

But when i run:

```
dovecot user fandi@icodeformoney.com
```

I got:

```
field   value
userdb lookup: user fandi@icodeformoney.com doesn't exist
```

I already got `virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`
 in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Content of `/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf`:

```
user = vimbadmin
password = mypass
hosts = 127.0.0.1
dbname = vimbadmin
table = mailbox
select_field = maildir
where_field = username
```

Please somebody help me debug / solve this problem.

---

Edit 1

My dovecot-sql.conf.ext

```
driver = mysql

connect = host=localhost user=vimbadmin password=mypass dbname=vimbadmin
default_pass_scheme = SHA512-CRYPT

password_query = SELECT username as user, password as password, \
    homedir AS userdb_home, maildir AS userdb_mail, \
    concat('*:bytes=', quota) as userdb_quota_rule, uid AS userdb_uid, gid AS userdb_gid \
  FROM mailbox \
    WHERE username = '%Lu' AND active = '1' \
    AND ( access_restriction = 'ALL' OR LOCATE( '%Us', access_restriction ) > 0 )

user_query = SELECT homedir AS home, maildir AS mail, \
    concat('*:bytes=', quota) as quota_rule, uid, gid \
  FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the problem with `dovecot -n`

Somehow i couldn't find in the config:

```
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
```

I found instead:

```
passdb {
  driver=pam
}
```

Then rather than going into each file back and forth, i did this (i was in my home directory):

```
sudo cp /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf.old
doveconf -n > dovecot.conf
sudo cp doveconf.conf /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
```

And fixed the passdb and userdb.

Comment: Though need to remember to fix the line: `ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it`

Answer (score 0):

what version of postfix and dovecot do you use?
How does the dovecot sql configuration looks like?
-> Postfix configuration is not responsible for dovecot.

A valid dovecot configuration (Attention configuration, sql query used for postfixadmin not vbadmin), should look like this:

/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf

```
    driver = mysql
connect = host=<dbhost> dbname=<maildb> user=<maildb> password=<password>
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
user_query = SELECT '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as home, 'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as mail, 303 AS uid, 303 AS gid, concat('dirsize:storage=', quota) AS quota FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
# Get the password
password_query = SELECT username as user, password, '/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_home, 'maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n' as userdb_mail, 303 as userdb_uid, 303 as userdb_gid FROM mailbox WHERE username = '%u' AND active = '1'
```

#### Replace Values <...> with your data.  my be 127.0.0.1

And must be implemented by:

```
    passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}

userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
```

By Include File:  /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-sql.conf
or in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

Based on an Opensuse 15.1 System and dovecot 2.3.3

Comment: What's not ok with my answer to rate it negative? Fandi Susanto?

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. I voted up. I dont know who voted down.

Answer (score 0):

Rename dovecot-sql.conf.ext to dovecot-sql.conf to be included.

What about dovecot.conf? Will it be included there?

Comment: I think `dovecot-sql.conf.ext` is supposed to be called from the `passdb` directive in `auth-sql.conf.ext` in conf.d. I can not figure out why it got `.ext` though. So i just take shortcut with doveconf

Answer (score 0):

@Fandi Susanto,

it's a valid way to use conf.d/* to be included.

But afaik the needed files should be renamed from *.conf.ext to *.conf. They are delivered as example but must be modified to your requirement. I think to avoid malefunctions or security issues the files will not be includes by default.